# Why did my Serializer stop recognizing a given required value?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following Model and Serializer:

**Model**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['company']
        unique_together = ['company', 'title']
```

**Serializer**

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Location
```

When I try to create a new Location using the Serializer:

```
lo = LocationSerializer(data={'title': 'test', 'company': 2})
```

I get back the following error:

```
{'company': ['This field is required.']}
```

What gives? The only thing I'd changed recently in either the Model or the Serializer was adding the `unique_together` constraint to the Model. Why is the Serializer now unable to recognize the `company` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the error message is a complete red herring. What's really happening is that there's an incompatibility between the `unique_together` constraint in the Model and `read-only` fields like `StringRelatedField` defined in the Serializer.

Removing `unique_together` from the Model restored the Serializer's functionality. Alternatively, you could remove the read-only field declaration from the Serializer. Neither really seem like an appropriate solution as they require sacrificing functionality in pretty major ways.

Right now there appears to be an [issue open on DRF's GitHub](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2547) related to this problem but it remains to be seen if this is Working As Intended<sup>tm</sup> or is in fact a bug.